# md5: is reverse length-extension attack possible?

Tags: hash, md5, length-extension

If I know

```
H = md5( SECRET_KEY | DATA )
```

then I can calculate

```
H' = md5( SECRET_KEY | DATA | DATA' )
```

That's length-extension attack. But is the opposite possible? E.g. if I know

```
H = md5( SECRET_KEY | DATA )
```

can I find

```
H'' = md5( SECRET_KEY )
```

where DATA is known and lenght of DATA is known too???

Basically, can I find md5 of the KEY without DATA (once again, DATA is known, H is known, but SECRET_KEY is unknown)?

Comment: A note: the description of the length-extension attacks omits restrictions on how `DATA'` must start.

Comment: Perhaps one might call such an attack a "length-contraction attack"? $\:$

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: **No**, there is no known practical attack in the setup given.

But we do not have an argument/proof that there is not one, and we should be less confident in that than we are in [HMAC-MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), for which we have [such an argument](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.pdf).

Comment: It is important to understand that Merkle–Damgård hashes were never designed to resist attacks of this type. Any properties like this that they have are just the result of pure luck.

Comment: It would mean we can invert $h \mapsto E_m(h) + h$ where $E$ is the block cipher out of which MD5's compression function is built.  This seems unlikely without serious cryptanalytic damage to $E$ (and it would presumably not have a unique answer most of the time).